# How to transfer options to /tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

In the following code, I want to typeset by the macro `\pageband`

- a band with color red on the middle of page.
- Three texts located at the left hand/middle/right hand of the band. The format of these text is controlled by the option style `text format`.

Q1:
Though I define the key `text format` and invoke it in the document body(First try), I don't explicitly use it at all in the defination of `\pageband`. Why dose it take effect(text with color yellow and with size huge bfseries)?

Q2:
The difference between my first try and second try in the code is that adding a extra option `rotate=90` to `text format`. This causes error. Why and how to solve it?

**Code：**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,tikz}
%
\pgfkeys{pageband/.cd,
  pos/.initial,
  width/.initial,
  height/.initial,
  color/.initial,
  /tikz/text format/.style={#1},
}
%
\newcommand\ppb[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pageband/#1}}
%
\newcommand\pageband[1]{
  \pgfkeys{pageband/.cd,/pageband/.search also={/tikz},#1}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    % step 1: draw band
    \node at([xshift=\ppb{pos}]current page.center)
    [color=\ppb{color}]
    {\rule{\ppb{width}}{\ppb{height}}};
    % step 2: typeset text in the above band
    \path ([xshift=-0.5\paperwidth]current page.center)--([xshift=0.5\paperwidth]current page.center)
    node[at start,anchor=west]{SSS}
    node[midway]{MMM}
    node[at end,anchor=east]{EEE};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
First try:\par % This does work
\pageband{pos=0pt,text format={color=yellow,font=\Huge\bfseries},color=red,width=\paperwidth,height=0.5in}

Second try:\par %fail and cause error
\pageband{pos=0pt,text format={color=yellow,font=\Huge\bfseries,rotate=90},color=red,width=\paperwidth,height=0.5in}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q1: Though I define the key text format and invoke it in the document body(First try), I don't explicitly use it at all in the defination of `\pageband`. Why dose it take effect (text with color yellow and with size huge bfseries)?

It takes effect, because at the end of the day, it just does

```
\def\tikz@textfont{\bfseries}
```

This macros doen't get reset at the start of a `tikzpicture` and stays until the end of a scope/group.

---

> Q2: The difference between my first try and second try in the code is that adding a extra option `rotate=90` to `text format`. This causes error. Why and how to solve it?

The key `rotate` on the other hand, does

```
\tikz@addtransform{\pgftransformrotate{90}}
```

and `\tikz@addtransform`'s first action is to compare `\tikz@transform` to relax. However, `\tikz@transform` is **not** initialized until shortly after `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

This has absolutely nothing to do with your key setup, it already happens with plain pdfTeX:

```
% arara: pdftex
\input tikz.tex
\tikzset{rotate=45}
\bye
```

Of course, it does have something to do with the `\pageband` definition. Your usage of `\pgfkeys` should not come before the `tikzpicture`.

I'd suggest also providing a `/pageband/tikz/.code=\tikzset{#1}` key so that the user has to put everything there when they want to use `/tikz` keys. That way, there's no conflict between `pageband/color` and `/tikz/color`.

That said, the nodes do not get rotated just because the scope gets `rotate = 90`. Nodes are immunite to transformations unless `transform shape` is used.

Answer (score 4):

I propose to use the fit library for the band and a second parameter for the angle of rotation.

```
\documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651749/how-to-transfer-options-to-tikz
\usepackage{geometry,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {fit}
%
\pgfkeys{pageband/.cd,
  pos/.initial,
  width/.initial,
  height/.initial,
  color/.initial,
  /tikz/text format/.style={#1},
}
% % %
  \newcommand\ppb[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pageband/#1}}
% % %

\newcommand\pageband[2]{\pgfkeys{pageband/.cd,/pageband/.search also={/tikz},#1}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,
    every node/.style={rotate=#2}]

    \node  (a) at([xshift=-\ppb{pos}]current page.center) {};
    \node  (b) at([xshift=\ppb{pos}]current page.center) {};
    \node[fill=\ppb{color},fit=(a) (b),minimum height=\ppb{height},minimum width=\ppb{width}] (fit) {};
    \node[right] at (fit.west) {West};
    \node at (fit.center) {Center};
    \node[left] at (fit.east) {East};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}
First try:\par % This does work
\pageband{pos=0pt,text format={color=yellow,font=\Huge\bfseries},color=red,width=\paperwidth,height=0.5in}{0}
Second try:\par %
\pageband{pos=0pt,text format={color=yellow,font=\Huge\bfseries},color=red,width=\paperwidth,height=0.5in}{90}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I'm still puzzled what's wrong with my code for my two questions. I think the reason may llie in how to transfer options  `/tikz` from outside(the key `text format` in this example).